# Pandas: Multiplying two columns of same dataframe thats dependent on third column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-science

How can I multiply two columns of within a same dataframe? My dataframe looks like below image and I want to output like this. However, I cannot find how to multiply two columns that are dependent on first row of same dataframe. I would really appreciate some help on this.

```
request                            totalbytes
/login                              8520
/shuttle/countdown/                 7970
/shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html     0
```

[image]

So far my output is below, but how can I get unique rows.
[image]

Comment: To multiply two columns, simply multiply them: `df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency']`. However, your expected result is _not_ a product of two columns. Please explain exactly what you want. The reference to the first row is especially puzzling.

Comment: I don't follow your question. First your title is different from your question; second, your desired output looks right as far as I can tell; third, apparently your *actual* desired outcome is something totally different (multiplying vs. getting unique elements). You can multiply columns like you would intuitively, and to get just the unique rows, there are plenty of resources out there. Please clarify your question. Thanks.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin: I am getting repeated values as shown in my 2nd image. How can I get total bytes for every unique URL. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @DYZ: My desired output is right under the question, the code-block. I tried pasting here but formatting gets skewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you explained what you want... You actually want to drop duplicates:

```
(df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency']).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems need simply multiple columns:

```
df['totalbytes'] = df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency']
```

Or use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
df['totalbytes'] = df['bytesbytes'].mul(df['bytesfrequency'])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'bytesbytes':[3985,1420,0,0],
                   'bytesfrequency':[2,6,2,2]})


df['totalbytes'] = df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency']
print (df)
   bytesbytes  bytesfrequency  totalbytes
0        3985               2        7970
1        1420               6        8520
2           0               2           0
3           0               2           0
```

But maybe need `groupby` by first column `request` and use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for create new `Series` which is multiple (both columns are converted by `transform`, maybe need only one):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'request':['a','a','b','b'],
                   'bytesbytes':[3985,1420,1420,0],
                   'bytesfrequency':[2,6,6,2]})


g = df.groupby('request')

print (g['bytesbytes'].transform('first'))
0    3985
1    3985
2    1420
3    1420
Name: bytesbytes, dtype: int64

print (g['bytesfrequency'].transform('first'))
0    2
1    2
2    6
3    6
Name: bytesfrequency, dtype: int64

df['totalbytes'] = g['bytesbytes'].transform('first')*g['bytesfrequency'].transform('first')
print (df)
   bytesbytes  bytesfrequency request  totalbytes
0        3985               2       a        7970
1        1420               6       a        7970
2        1420               6       b        8520
3           0               2       b        8520
```

EDIT:

If need remove duplicates by `request` column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'request':['a','a','b','b'],
                   'bytesbytes':[3985,1420,1420,0],
                   'bytesfrequency':[2,6,6,2]})

print (df)
   bytesbytes  bytesfrequency request
0        3985               2       a
1        1420               6       a
2        1420               6       b
3           0               2       b
```

---

One line solution - [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), multiple and last [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('request')
       .assign(totalbytes=df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency'])
       .drop(['bytesbytes','bytesfrequency'], axis=1)
print (df)
  request  totalbytes
0       a        7970
2       b        8520
```

```
df = df.drop_duplicates('request')
df['totalbytes'] = df['bytesbytes']*df['bytesfrequency']
df = df.drop(['bytesbytes','bytesfrequency'], axis=1)
print (df)
  request  totalbytes
0       a        7970
2       b        8520
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I get totalbytes for all unique requests. So I need just two columns: uniquerequests and totalbytes. Just as I have shown under the question, in code block. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: I think need last answer - `drop_duplicates` , multiple and last `drop` columns.

Answer (score 1):

Short way to get your posted expected results

```
df.drop_duplicates().set_index('request').prod(1).reset_index(name='totalbytes')

                           request  totalbytes
0               /shuttle/countdown        7970
1                           /login        8520
2  /shuttle/countdown/liftoff.html           0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your title because it's *very* misleading.

Also, to answer your question, `pandas` has a handy [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method. I strongly suggest you check it out.

In a nutshell, the method literally drops all duplicate rows and returns a new `DataFrame`. Optionally, you can make the method only consider certain rows - details can be found in the docs.

In your case, you could simply do:

```
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()[['requests', 'totalbytes']]
```

Column indexing is totally optional, but I added them because I thought you wanted only those two columns in your final output.